# Formstack embed breaking AEM emulator layout

Tags: aem, formstack

I'm using formstack form in the AEM pages using formstack embed script which I add in the pages using HTML component. The form appears to work as expected. However I'm noticing some issues with the AEM emulator where it's not working when this embed is added to the pages. Attached below is the console error I get trying the emulator options.
AEM Version: 6.5.10

[image]

I've tried using no jquery in the embed to check it has got anything with the jquery, but it appears not. When using iframe the issue is not observed, however it's preferred not to use an iframe.

Has anyone came across some similar issues with embed script with any projects and I would like to know how it was resolved? Or any pointers to the right direction would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you re-upload the screenshot its to small to see i'm afraid

Comment: Perfect, that's much better thank you